# Why is this question put on hold?

Tags: discussion

How can this question be off topic and put on hold ? [How can I overcome 'lack of local experience'](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13898/how-can-i-overcome-lack-of-local-experience?noredirect=1#comment33581_13898)
It asks a specific question and is tagged appropriately.

Similar questions have been answered before : [How can I overcome "years of experience" requirements when applying to positions?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1478/how-can-i-overcome-years-of-experience-requirements-when-applying-to-positions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first thought when I saw it on the front page (didn't have time at the time to read it) was that it could end up being a duplicate of the second question you've linked.

While that may be the case (I'm not completely convinced; it could be different enough), I do disagree with the current closure. I've reopened it, but I wouldn't be surprised if it got closed again (as a duplicate).

Comment: I searched and no one faced the situation I talk about in the thread. Though it may be closely related to the other linked question (which I searched today so I could understand why such questions are not entertained and puts in hazard my near future of being question banned) I believe the community can collectively help, me and future seekers of such a question, with their answers. Thanks for reopening.

Answer (score 5):

I personally voted to close the question because, as jmac pointed out in a comment, you seem to be asking four different questions, like: "(1) what is 'local experience' (2) how do you overcome unwritten requirements (3) what do Australian IT employers/recruiters want (4) how should I handle this job rejection".

I'm not sure which, really, is your primary question, or how close these assumed questions are to your primary question, but if these four do encompass your questions, I would say that 1 is possibly answerable although with a lot of conjecture unless it is something specific to Australia and someone here knows that, 2 I believe has a duplicate somewhere on this site but I haven't looked yet, 3 is really broad, and 4 is probably unanswerable by the community.

But as with everything, a focused question is a better question.